# LTSpice (Berkeley Spice) Files. WHERE?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, kicad, pspice

I am working on importing spice files into Fusion 360 Electrical. It accepts original spice files. Is this something common, where can I find it, etc. I am used to finding the footprint, symbol, 3d model through samacsys ECAD libraries. Is it contained in that folder menu for a similar software? I see that autodesk posts "As long as its a pure Spice model, change it to .mdl" I cant find any pure spice models. Do you guys generally do circuit analysis through fusion or through another way? Is there a circuit analysis like kicad that will have the model included in the ECAD files? For instance I need SMAJ58A. How can I get one of those spice models into a simulator?

Comment: Do a search for on the Internet for SPICE models. For instance, searching for "SMAJ58A spice model" (without the quotes) and you'll find a few models from various manufacturers.

Comment: Seems like the EE side of engineering is not quite as buttoned up as it could be, especially from the component manufacturer side. I bet you could make a killing developing a file package that includes footprint, symbol, 3d model, and spice model in one. If thats not possible, an AI software built into fusion that brings suggested files to the user to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the models from either the manufacturer or another party that has modeled the device.

> It is possible in LTspice IV to create a new symbol from scratch for a
> third-party model but who has the time? Follow these easy steps to
> generate a new symbol for a third-party model defined in a subcircuit
> (.SUBCKT statement).
>
> Open the netlist file that contains the subcircuit definitions in LTspice (File > Open or drag file into LTspice)
> Right-click the line containing the name of the subcircuit, and select Create
> To use the new symbol (and associated third party model) in a schematic, select the symbol from the AutoGenerated directory in the
> component library (F2) and place it in your schematic:
>
> Select Component Symbol
>
> By using the automatic symbol generation you can focus on your
> simulations, not creating new symbols. For a more information on how
> to import third party models that use intrinsic SPICE device (.MODEL
> statement) see the video at [www.linear.com/solutions/1083](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1083).

Source:
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Answer (score 1):

Tracking down and integrating SPICE models into a simulation is usually a bit of an adventure. There are many SPICE dialects and no standard. The model files are often proprietary and cannot legally be distributed in CAD libraries.

That said, searching for "smaj58a spice model" gets plenty of hits.